# Font-family iFrame body

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, font-family

I've got an iFrame inside a body tag as follows:

```
<body onLoad="iFrameOn();">
    <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>
</body>
```

The javascript iFrameOn looks like this:

```
function iFrameOn() {
    richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
    richTextField.document.body.style.fontFamily = "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Unfortunately, the font doesn't change to the font I tell it to change to. The error console from the javascript says: "Helvetica is not defined(...)".
How can I solve this, so the font in the iFrame is the one I declare it to be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should set them as one string,

```
richTextField.document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Open Sans, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';
```

Comment: It was that simple. I feel stupid now. Thanks. I'll mark it as answer in 10min. Stackoverflow things...

Answer (score 2):

you can change your ifram style; add a font-face to it using this code; that worked for me :)

```
var myframe = $('#iframeId');
var myframStyle = myframe[0].contentWindow.document.children[0].children[0].getElementsByTagName('style');
var myframeStyleContent = myframe[0].contentWindow.document.children[0].children[0].getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML;
var myfontFace = "@font-face {font-family: your-fontname; font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;src: url('your web font url') format('woff2');} body {font-family:your-fontname;}"; 
myframeStyleContent += myfontFace;
myframe[0].contentWindow.document.children[0].children[0].getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML = myframeStyleContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code:

```
richTextField.contentDocument.body.style.fontFamily = '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, San Francisco, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif';
```